# Render only objects being scattered using geometry nodes

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, masking

this my first time using geometry nodes. How do I render only objects being scattered on a plane? [image]

Comment: what do you mean? so you don't want to render the plane?

Comment: Remove the Join Geometry node and do not connect de Group Input directly with the Group Output.

Comment: @Chris Yes, only the objects being scattered around on that plane are to be rendered without the plane.

Comment: @AndréZmuda It works! thank you.